# How can I move custom shortcuts to another machine using a dotfiles repository?

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts, kde

I'm currently creating a repository with dotfiles to replicate some settings easily on a fresh Kubuntu install. Since I have set a couple of shortcuts, I would also like to move them to the new machine.

In my .config I found the file "kglobalshortcutsrc" which lists all of my shortcuts, but when I tried to move them to another machine, the shortcuts do not work there and the file simply gets overwritten as soon as I open the Shortcuts Dialog on the new machine.

I know that you can import and export shortcut files from the dialog, but to automate things I would like to manage it using dotfiles. Any ideas on how to make that work?

I am using Kubuntu 18.04 with KDE Frameworks Version 5.47.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been doing [this](https://gitlab.com/victor-engmark/tilde) for a few years now. The main file of interest to you is probably the [Makefile](https://gitlab.com/victor-engmark/tilde/blob/master/Makefile) which, among other things, creates symlinks to the repository content rather than copying it. That way it's simple to keep track of which applications overwrite which configuration files, and version control as needed.

In your specific case it sounds like a process reads the kglobalshortcutsrc file at startup and writes it to disk whenever you open the shortcuts dialogue. The simplest way to work around something like this is typically to stop whichever process overwrites this file, create the symlink, and start the process back up again.

Some processes behave badly and actually replace the symlink with a proper file. Usually a simple workaround for this is to symlink the parent directory of the file - the process is very unlikely to replace the entire directory structure at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Following up my own questiong.

A short time after I asked this, I started using NixOS and soon found [plasma-manager](https://github.com/pjones/plasma-manager) to be exactly what I was looking for, as I wasn't very keen on figuring out myself where all the configuration files were located.

As far as I'm concerned this seems like the best approach to declaratively manage a KDE Plasma configuration to be able to reproducibly install it on any host.